# Canvas - Arc suddenly vanishes

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

So I'm making a basic clock just for fun with minute and second arcs. However, after a new minute starts, the minute arc quickly vanishes from the canvas. Why?

Here is a **JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/y0bson6f/

***HTML***

```
<canvas id="clock"></canvas>
```

***CSS***

```
body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Josefin Sans, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #1A4978;
}
```

***JS***

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('clock');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function setDimensions() {
        context.canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.69;
        context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    }

    setDimensions();

    var x = 0.5 * canvas.width;
    var y = canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 0.25 * context.canvas.width;
    var startAngle = 0;
    var endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
    var startAnimationMinuteDone = false;
    var firstTime = false;

    function updateMinute(start, end) {
        if (startAnimationMinuteDone == false && firstTime == false) {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }

        setDimensions();
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = "#FF7519";
        context.arc(x, y, radius, start, end);
        context.lineWidth = 20;
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }

    function updateSecond(start, end) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = "#FFA319";
        radius = 0.25 * context.canvas.width + 20;
        context.arc(x, y, radius, start, end);
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }

    function minuteAntialias(start, end) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        setDimensions();
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = "#1A4978";
        context.arc(x, y, radius, start, end);
        context.lineWidth = 20;
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }

    function secondAntialias(start, end) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = "#1A4978";
        radius = 0.25 * context.canvas.width + 40;
        context.arc(x, y, radius, start, end);
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var time = 0;
        var count = 0;

        function clock() {
            var date = new Date();
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            var month = date.getMonth();
            var day = date.getDay();
            var hour = date.getHours();

            if (hour > 12) {
                hour -= 12;
            }

            var minute = date.getMinutes();
            var second = date.getSeconds();

            var newestMinuteStart = (time + 1.5) * Math.PI;
            var newestSecondStart = (time + 1.5) * Math.PI;

            var cachedTime;

            if (count <= minute / 30 && !startAnimationMinuteDone) {
                time += 0.01;
                updateMinute(1.5 * Math.PI, (time + 1.5) * Math.PI);
                count += 0.01;
                cachedTime = time;

            } else if (!startAnimationMinuteDone) {
                time = 0;
                count = 0;
                startAnimationMinuteDone = true;

            } else if (count <= second / 30 || second == 0 && startAnimationMinuteDone) {
                time += 0.01;
                updateSecond(1.5 * Math.PI, (time + 1.5) * Math.PI);
                secondAntialias(0, 2 * Math.PI); // Arc matching background colour gives the effect of greater sharpness
                count += 0.01;

                if (second == 0) {
                    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    startAnimationMinuteDone = false;
                    firstTime = true;
                    time = 0;
                    count = 0;
                }

                console.log(second);
                console.log(startAnimationMinuteDone);
            }
        }

        setInterval(clock, 10);
    });
```

Comment: minute arc does not actually vanish but second arc overdraws minute arc after a second passed because second radius becomes equal to minute radius. change radius of both minute and second arc and you'll see it. you could use different radii of both arcs.  and by the way nice clock ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant by using different radii of both minute and second arc and in this example the interval to show current time is 1 second and not 10 milliseconds that consumes a great deal of cpu. I would keep animations and time separate from one another:

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
var width = can.width;
var height = can.height;

// because arc start at an angle of 0 rad or 0 deg you have to rotate/translate the canvas so that they start at an angle of PI/2 rad or 90 deg
ctx.rotate(-degtorad(90));
ctx.translate(-width,0);

var x = width*0.5;
var y = height*0.5;

var minradius = width*0.45;
var secradius = width*0.25;

function degtorad(deg){ return deg*(Math.PI/180); }

function updateMinute(start, end) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFA319";
    ctx.arc(x, y, minradius, start, end);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function updateSecond(start, end) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#1A4978";
    ctx.arc(x, y, secradius, start, end);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

setInterval(function(){

    var date = new Date();
    var min = date.getMinutes();
    var sec = date.getSeconds();

    var secdeg = sec*6;
    var mindeg = min*6;

    console.log('secdeg: ',secdeg, sec);
    console.log('mindeg: ',mindeg, min);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width,height);

    updateMinute(0,degtorad(mindeg));
    updateSecond(0,degtorad(secdeg));


},1000);
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```